# Как сделать фигурное выделение текста

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как правильно прописать код, чтобы получилось так как на картинке. Я не верстальщик, но очень нужно сделать

[image]

Comment: самое простое - сделать блоку фоновое изображение, картинкой или svg. требует минимум знаний верстки

Answer (score 4):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: red;
  background-clip: content-box;
  color: white;
}

div::before, div::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: solid;
}

div::before {
  border-width: 2em 1em 0 0;
  border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

div::after {
  border-width: 1em 1em 1em 0;
  border-color: red transparent red red;
  margin-right: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div> 789 руб </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ещё проще:

```css
div {
  display: table; background: red; color: white; margin: 5px; padding: 7px 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(20px 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 20px) 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>789 789 789 789 789 руб</div><div>789 789 789 789 руб</div><div>789 789 789 руб</div><div>789 789 руб</div><div>789 руб</div><div>7 руб</div><div>7</div>
```

Comment: Ну зачем же в процентах-то по горизонтали??

Comment: Потому что от длины текста будет зависеть, а логично чтобы хвосты были фиксированных размеров.

Comment: clip-path - поддерживается полностью только firefox, могут быть проблемы с таким написанием.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так например

```css
.bage {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px 6px 5px 10px;
    transform: skewX(-20deg)
}

.bage:after, .bage:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border: 17px solid transparent;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
    right: -14px;
    z-index: -1
}

.bage:before {
    top: 0;
    border-top-color: red
}

.bage:after {
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-color: red
}

.bage__text {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: skewX(20deg)
}
```

```html
<span class="bage">
    <span class="bage__text">789 руб</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Ну треугольники - это ж классика...

Comment: именно ) можно и чище написать без лишней обертки

Comment: Я у себя левый треугольник исправил. Оказывается, невнимательно вопрос прочитал...

Comment: отлично получилось

Answer (score 2):

linear-gradient пример

```css
div{
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, tomato 70%,transparent 30%),
              linear-gradient(135deg, tomato 70%,transparent 30%);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 90px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-80deg, tomato 70%, transparent 0%);
}
```

```html
<div>789789 руб</div>
<div>78999999руб</div>
<div>78999999999руб</div>
<div>78999999999999999 руб </div>
```

Пример на transform: matrix

```css
.price{
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

.price:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: matrix(1,0,-0.5,1,1,0);
}

.text{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.minusmatrix,.plusmatrix{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.minusmatrix{
  background: lightgreen;
  transform: matrix(1,0,0.5,1,0,0);
}
.plusmatrix{
  background: lightgreen;
  transform: matrix(1,0,-0.5,1,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <div class="minusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="plusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="text">999 руб</div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="minusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="plusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="text">9999 руб</div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="minusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="plusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="text">99999 руб</div>
</div>

<div class="price">
  <div class="minusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="plusmatrix"></div>
  <div class="text">9999999999 руб</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Можно загрузить картинку фоном, например:

css:
background: url(../img/fon.png) no-repeat center center;

Comment: при разном количестве контента она деформироваться будет

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, можно 2 картинки на фон или одну, но на border-image. Но без картинок лучше :)

Comment: Тоже вариант, но лучше все таки на голом css. Просто работает быстрее и без лишних запросов